# Need Help with ASP.NET (3.5) ScriptManager to call WCF JSON Data via AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf, scriptmanager

I am trying to get ASP.NET (Framework 3.5), AJAX, and JSON to work. I have two questions along those lines. This first is, when I add the below tag as required by ASP.NET:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = 
      AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

I find that I cannot add it above an interface declaration, only a class. I want this code to be an interface. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong? The error is as follows:

> Attribute
>   AspNetCompatibilityRequirements is not
>   valid on this declaration type. It is
>   only valid on 'class' declarations.

```
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "API.Trade")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = 
        AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public interface ITradeService
    {
        [OperationContract(Name = "GetAllCategories")]
        string GetCategories(string itemtype, string keywordstring);

        [OperationContract(Name = "GetCategoryByNodeLevel")]
        string GetCategories(int NodeLevel); 

        [OperationContract]
        int GetTrades(string KeywordString, string TradeType);
    }
```

THE SECOND question is, in the ASPX ScriptManager tag:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
 <Services>
 <asp:ServiceReference Path="?" />
 </Services>
 </asp:ScriptManager>
```

I notice that the Path= attribute should be pointing to a .SVC file. So far, I have 
successfully been using a WCF Class Library to accomplish what I need. The Class Library 
has the Trade.cs, TradeService.cs, and ITradeService.cs files which I compile and then 
reference as my Web Service in my Web project.

So, what should "Path=" be pointing to? Or, what do I need to add?

I am learning as I go and I appreciate your patience. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the first question. The attribute is defined to be only applicable to a class, so you can't declare it on anything else.

The path should point to the endpoint where your service is listening (e.g. /services/myserivce).

Answer (score 0):

The path ought to be the service endpoint for an HTTP service: `http://host.example.com/tradeservice.svc/method`.

You can only apply the attribute to an implementation of the interface (a class) not the interface itself.

Answer (score 0):

As for your second answer.  I believe the path needs to point to a actual webservice endpoint (.svc or the old one.. I forget off the top my head, sorry).

What you can do is create a WebService, TradeService.svc, and implement the ITradeService interface.  As a private variable on the service create a instance of TradeService, and use it as a proxy... like so

```
private TradeService _proxy;

public string MyMethod(){
    _proxy.MyMethod();
}
```

make sence.

Comment: Hi Aquillin,
Thanks for that. I get the gist of what you are saying but am geting caught up with how to expose the interfaces I created in my class library. I am assuming that I need to add a USING directive to ITradeService and then make a reference to the interface methods (MyMethod) in the DLL which I can then use in "_proxy.MyMethod". I am not really sure how to go about this - can you show me what the code should look like for ITradeService after adding the WCF Class Library that I have? I hop I have made sense here...

Answer (score 0):

- AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute.RequirementsMode is not a required attribute  and can be used for setting the hosting mode programmatically Or you can do the same
  in webconfig by using serviceHostingEnvironment tag:

```
    <system.serviceModel> 
    <serviceHostingEnvironment ..>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Reference : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.aspnetcompatibilityrequirementsattribute.requirementsmode(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.aspnetcompatibilityrequirementsattribute.requirementsmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

- You should add a service host(.svc) in your project by manually adding
  TradeService.svc. You can also do same by adding new item > WCF
  Service but that will override your service cs files. Once you have
  your svc file added then you can add following line:

```
 
     <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="TradeService" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Note that **WebScriptServiceHostFactory** will automatically add ASP.NET Ajax endpoint to your service. Finally point your "path" attribute to this newly created "TradeService.svc".

You can test your service by visiting http://localhost.me/TradeService.svc

And Ajax support can be tested at http://localhost.me/TradeService.svc/jsdebug

Reference : http://berniecook.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/consuming-a-wcf-service-with-jquery-or-scriptmanager/

SourceCode : https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bz2usIBCcor0NDQxZDc2ODYtNTUzMi00OTRlLTlhOGMtMGI4Y2RhNGIzYWNj